# Eclipse IDE issues on mac Monetery with JDK 17.0.1

Tags: java, eclipse, macos-monterey

I have installed JDK 17.0.1 on Mac os Monterey (latest mac OS)

1. Installed JDK 17.0.1 then configured JAVA_HOME
2. Installed latest Eclipse version
3. Launch it and doesn't do anyhthing.

At first it was throwing an error due to the JAVA_HOME not set in the info.pilst file.
I updated the info file and still no joy.
Any help would be appreciated.
Otherwise I have to got the Intelli J route.

Comment: I have installed the latest eclipse IDE downloaded from the website.
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: So you downloaded 'eclipse-inst-jre-mac64.dmg'? And ran the Eclipse Installer app? Running that should ask you for the JDK location. I just ran an install here and it worked fine. [edit] your question and add more details.

Comment: _Latest_ is not a proper version number. Please note, the latest Eclipse at the time you asked is already out of date now. Are there any reasons why not using the Java 17 that is provided as part of the current Eclipse 2021-12?

Comment: What was that original error message, exactly?

Comment: I have installed Eclipse Latest Version 4.22 if that helps anything. yes- installed the 'eclipse-inst-jre-mac64.dmg' file. When I open Eclipse I dont get any error message now. It just does nothing at all.